# MySQL Precison Issues in DECIMAL NUMERIC data type

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, precision, stored-functions

In writing a function for scientific application, I ran into issues. I traced it back to MySQL's lack of precison.

Here is the page from the official documentation which claims that **The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65** - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html . It also describes how the value will be rounded if it exceeds the specified precison.

Here is reproducible code (a mysql stored function) to test it -

```
  DELIMITER $$
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test$$
  CREATE FUNCTION test
      (xx DECIMAL(30,25)
      )
      RETURNS DECIMAL(30,25)
      DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
      DECLARE result DECIMAL(30,25);
      SET result = 0.339946499848118887e-4;
      RETURN(result);
   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
```

If you save the code above in a file called **test.sql**, you can run it by executing the following in mysql prompt -

```
source test.sql;
select test(0);
```

It produces the output -

```
+-----------------------------+
| test(0)                     |
+-----------------------------+
| 0.0000339946499848118900000 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the number is getting rounded at the 20th digit, and then five zeroes are being added to it to get to the required/specified precison. That is cheating.

Am I mistaken, or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: +1 . . . I've verified that this is the case even with `cast(0.0000339946499848118887' as decimal(60, 25))`.  I thought the problem might be the floating point constant, but it is happening with string to decimal conversion as well.

Comment: Update: I found that, in declaring DECIMAL(M, D), MySQL returns an error when D>30. I couldn't find official documentation for it, but I suppose 30 is the limit for D. But the findings above contradict that as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I don't know much about SQL, but in a mysql shell, the statement `select cast('0.0000339946499848118887' as decimal(60, 25));` returns `0.0000339946499848118887000` as expected. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about SQL, but my guess would be this line:

```
  SET result = 0.339946499848118887e-4;
```

If MySQL is anything like other languages I know, then this will first evaluate the right-hand side, and *then* assign the value to `result`. No matter what type `result` is declared to be or what precision it's declared to have, it wouldn't matter if the right-hand side has already lost precision when being evaluated. This is almost surely what is happening here.

I can reproduce your results, but If I change that line to

```
  SET result = cast('0.339946499848118887e-4' as decimal(30, 25));
```

(casting from a string instead of from a floating-point constant of unspecified precision) then I correctly get

```
+-----------------------------+
| test(0)                     |
+-----------------------------+
| 0.0000339946499848118887000 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

as desired. So that's your fix.

---

BTW, the documentation that `scale` in `DECIMAL(precision, scale)` cannot be greater than 30 seems to be in section [12.19.2. DECIMAL Data Type Changes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.6 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Comment: Oh I guess my 'cast' and 'decimal' could be uppercase too. But I don't understand why there's so much shouting in idiomatic SQL. :-)

Comment: Anshul's answer below clarifies that MySQL treats the numbers differently depending on how they are written!

Answer (score 3):

This happens because mysql treats `0.339946499848118887e-4` as `float` and  treats `0.0000339946499848118887` as `fixed point`.

```
mysql> select cast(  0.339946499848118887e-4 as DECIMAL(30, 25));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| cast(  0.339946499848118887e-4 as DECIMAL(30, 25)) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        0.0000339946499848118900000 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast(  0.0000339946499848118887 as DECIMAL(30, 25));
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| cast(  0.0000339946499848118887 as DECIMAL(30, 25)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                         0.0000339946499848118887000 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As described in the mysql documentation on [precision math - expression handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-expressions.html) -

> If any approximate values are present, the expression is approximate and is evaluated using floating-point arithmetic.

Quoting from, the documentation on [numerical types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-numbers.html),

> Two numbers that look similar may be treated differently. For example, 2.34 is an exact-value (fixed-point) number, whereas 2.34E0 is an approximate-value (floating-point) number.

Comment: I think both of these answers could have been the right answer. Had to toss a coin to choose one of them! Illuminating answer, thanks.